# How to swap a route's action and param id around

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a url redirect controller called "go". It can redirect topic model and company models. The route.rb looks like this:

```
  resources :go, only: [] do
    member do
      get :topic
      get :company
    end
  end
```

Currently it produce the following route:

```
topic_go GET      /go/:id/topic(.:format)        go#topic
company_go GET    /go/:id/company(.:format)      go#company
```

Is there a good way to make the route to be like this:

```
/go/topic/:id
/go/company/:id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `member` block entirely and add these two lines above `resources :go`.

```
get '/go/topic/:id' => 'go#topic', :as => :topic_go
get '/go/company/:id' => 'go#company', :as => :company_go
```